# Time lapse plotting

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am new to R environment. I have generated a simulated time lapse plot using the following code.

```
seq_x<-seq(1,10)
seq_y<-function(y)
{
z<-y^2+y+1
return (c(z))
}
yrange<-seq_y(1)
yrange[2]<-seq_y(length(seq_x))
for(i in 1:length(seq_x) )
{
xdata<-seq_x[1:i]
ydata<-seq_y(xdata)
plot(xdata,ydata,xlim=range(seq_x),ylim=range(yrange),type="o",col="royalblue",plot.first=grid())
Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

I get the following plot(after the final iteration).
[image]

Now I need to plot a straight line and a circle right across the plot as shown below.

[image]

The straight line should grow with the data sequence. The circle should be at the center of the data sequence with user specified radius. Any advice in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#draw circle
require(plotrix)
userRadius <- 1
draw.circle(median(xdata), median(ydata), userRadius)

#draw line
segments(x0=xdata[1],y0=ydata[1],
         x1=xdata[length(xdata)],y1=ydata[length(ydata)])
```

Comment: Thanks zx8754 I'll try that ! But can you suggest any technique using existing function.

Comment: Use above code after your lapsed plot is complete (after for loop).

Comment: I am getting both the line and the circle after the end of the plot. But I require the line to plotted along with the data sequence in increments.

Comment: Try pasting `#draw line` code below your `plot` code inside the loop?

Comment: circle is getting plotted with the data sequence in increments! But the straight line is still updated in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lines` to add additional lines to your plot. Then you just have to calculate the points on the circle (or ellipsis) and you can draw both the extra line and the circle.

```
# data
x <- seq(1,10)
y <- x^2 + x + 1
# function to calculate points on the ellipsis
ellipsis_fct <- function(mx, my, rx, ry){
  phi <- seq(0, 2*pi, length = 100) # change length if you need better resolution
  data.frame(x = mx + rx*sin(phi), 
             y = my + ry*cos(phi))
}
# actually calculate the points. 
circ <- ellipsis_fct(mean(range(x)), mean(range(y)), diff(range(x))/5, diff(range(y))/5)
# plotting commands
plot(x, y, xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y), type="o", col="royalblue", plot.first=grid())
lines(range(x), range(y), col = "darkred", lty = "dashed")
lines(circ, col = "orange")
```

Comment: I got both line and the circle! But how to include the above code inside my code snippet loop so as to get incremental plot.